# changing order direction after initialization

Tags: javascript, datatables

As title says, I'm trying to change the order direction of some columns after the table has been initialized. I've tried :

```
table = $("#my_table").dataTable();
var settings = table.fnSettings();
settings.aoColumnDefs = [{ 'asSorting': ['desc'], 'aTargets': ['_all'] }]
```

but this does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot. Reinitialize the table with the new settings.